# Define object through another objects then initialize those objects in Python

Tags: python, class, object, instance, variable-assignment

Hi I want to define an object value as a sum of values of two objects of the same class before I know what the value of those 2 objects is. 
I need to do something like:

```
`A=: B+C
 B=10
 C=20 
 print A`
```

I have a class `Set` and I'm trying something like:

```
class Set(object):
    def __init__(self, w):
        self.value=w
a=Set
c=a
a(10)
print c
```

But c is still class instead of object instance. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a class `Set` and so is `c`. `a(10)` generates an instance but discards it right away. You need to create instances and assign values later. Something like that:

```
class Sum(object):
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self.values = values

    @property
    def value(self):
        return sum(v.value for v in self.values)

class Value(object):
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value=value

b = Value()
c = Value()
a = Sum(b,c)
b.value = 10
c.value = 20
print a.value
```

Comment: it doesn't work, gives me `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Value' and 'Value'` error

Comment: and then if I do         `b = Value()
c = Value()
a = Sum(b.value,c.value)
b.value = 10
c.value = 20
print a.value`  I get a.value=0, which should be 30.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to leverage **dict** of object. You can use `__dict__` function of class.

```
class First:
    a = "A"
    b = "B"
    c = "C"

class Second:
    a = None
    b = None
    c = None
    d = "D"
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Now you can initialize Second class, using First class instance as follows:

```
first = First()
second = Second(**(first.__dict__))
print(second.a)
```